# Apache Rewrite: Redirect all pages except a few to the home page

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

I am using Apache 2.2.3 for several domains and, for one of those domains, I am trying to redirect all pages with the exception of a few (say, `page1` and `page2`) to the root `www.domain2.com`.  I want all other sites to be unaffected.

(The following should resolve to `www.domain2.com/page1`)
`www.domain2.com/page1`

(The following should resolve to `www.domain2.com`)
`www.domain2.com/page3`

The following is what I am trying and it is not working.  Essentially, for all requests to `www.domain2.com` I want all pages (save `page1` and `page2`) to resolve to the root (`www.domain2.com`). I am having trouble with the negation (all pages except):

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^.*domain2\.com [nc]
RewriteRule ^.*domain2.com!(|/|/page1|/page2)$ http://www.domain2.com [r=301,nc,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This would redirect everything requested at domain2 (except page1 and otherpage) to the equivalent page at domain1

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*.domain2.com [NC]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page1.html
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/otherpage.html
>
> RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain1.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Example: www.domain2.com/index.html -> www.domain1.com/index.html

Duplicate the rewriteconds inside (or use regex like `!^/(page1|otherpage)\.html` as you need.